# Visual Studio: How to tell exe where to look for dll's?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, directory, exe

I have a .lib included in my project (Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies) that makes my .exe build require a corresponding .dll to be provided with the .exe. Naturally, I would put the .dll in the same folder as .exe and that works fine, but I want to have only the .exe in the main folder and all other files, along with this .dll, in a subdirectory. How do I make the .exe look for it in that directory?

Just for clarification, I don't need VS to look for the .dll, but the program(.exe), after it has been built. Sorry if this was already asked, but I just can't find the right answer.

Comment: This is only easy to do with a .config file, `<probing>` element.  Windows 7/Server 2008 R2 or later required, that's usually where it ends.

Comment: Can you please write down how? It still doesn't seem ,,easy'' :D

Answer (score 0):

**Temporary solution:**
Apparently this is much harder than I thought, just like Hans said. However, I have stumbled upon a neat trick which can somewhat make it look like this, and that is to create an internal .exe and put it into a subfolder with the .dll's, while it is just executed from a main .exe. ShellExecute command can be used to do this. Anyway, if anyone know how to actually do the real thing, please write it down :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Hans Passant commented, I've solved it in my project (**C#/WPF/vs2019**) by editing `app.config` to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  ...
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="External"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Note that my output dir tree is like:

```
bin/
|--<myapp>.exe
|--External
    |--nuget1.dll
    |--nuget2.dll
```

You can specify multiple paths by delimiting them with semicolon.

For more information, see [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element).